# Vue js SSR: Can I have a multi-page single-page application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

I know this sounds like a massive contradiction and it is, but I don't know how to otherwise phrase it.

It seems like with vue server-side-rendering one can only have single page applications.

But for several reasons I need to have an application with multiple real server side generated pages with *real* URLs and each of them behave like the single page applications which vue js provides.

e.g. these would be the server side routes(i.e. URLs):

```
/
/contact
/articles
/authors
```

And then I'd like to be able to *mount* the vue client routing on each server generated page like

```
/articles/lastweek
/articles/nextweek
```

where lastweek and nextweek would be client side routes. Same for authors

```
/authors/sports
/authors/politics
/authors/lifestyle
```

where sports, politics and lifestyle would client side routes.

So /articles and /authors would behave like they were each a single page application except that they aren't, since they are are server generated pages.

I hope that doesn't sound too weird.

Comment: I mean, sure you could do this. No reason you can't. Only handle the routing for the top level categories, and use vue-router for the children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this! We just starting implementing vue in this exact fashion at my work. All you need to do is include the vue.js scripts on each server generated page, then just have a different vue app for each server view. We use the folder structure to keep it organized.

```
src
--content
----articles
------lastweek.css
------lastweek.js
------nextweek.css
------nextweek.js
----author
------sports.css
------sports.js
....
```

So each view would get it's own `css` and `js`. The `js` is the vue app for the view. You can structure your project in whatever way works best for your project, I just wanted to post an example.

Comment: I was sort of thinking along these lines too. It's just, that there are hardly any examples for this scenario. Especially in connection with webpack and css extraction and all the other nice stuff, you get with vue. Anyway thanks, so at least I know others have similar ideas.